# Motherboard for DDR4 2400+ MHz

Tags: motherboard, memory

I am preparing to buy a new desktop PC as the old one is 8 years already and not really upgradable. I see there are DDR4 modules running at 2133MHz and others running at 3200 MHz.

However, I have seen motherboards supporting only DDR4 2133MHz, or DDR4 2133MHz + DDR4 2400+ MHz OC (like this [ASRock Z170](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z170%20Extreme7+/?cat=Specifications)). What I understand is that in order to run at higher than 2133MHz speed, overclock is needed.

- Is there a motherboard that supports DDR4 modules running at 3200MHz (or any greater than 2133 MHz) out of the box?

This RAM overclocking is completely new to me and still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think that it is more technical support question but  I will say few words about it.

**Explanation:**

- [Super user explanation what OC memory in MOBO description means.](https://superuser.com/a/560832/564989)
- What does it mean for you ? It means that your motherboard will support memory up to 3600 MHz in dual-channel and up to 3866 MHz in single-channel. You have to load RAM [XMP profile](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/extreme-memory-profile-xmp.html) and it will work with desired frequency.

**My proposition:**

[ASRock Z170 Extreme7+](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z170%20Extreme7+/?cat=Specifications) is very good motherboard but only if you want overclock your new setup if not [Z170 chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/90591) will give you only support for higher frequency RAM what won't give proportional efficiency to the price paid for it. So if you won't overclock you should look for motherboards on [H110](http://ark.intel.com/products/90590/Intel-GL82H110-PCH) or [B150](http://ark.intel.com/products/90592/Intel-GL82B150-PCH) chipset and 2133 Mhz RAM with lowest CL.

B150 recommendation:

- [B150M MORTAR](https://msi.com/Motherboard/B150M-MORTAR.html#hero-specification) - [$90 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130890)

H110 recommendation:

- [H110M PRO-VD](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H110M-PRO-VD.html#hero-overview) - [$56 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130897)

Comment: Good answer. I have additional question, let me know if it is better to submit it as a new question. According to the specification, is ASRock Z170 Pro4S enough for support of a stock 3200 MHz RAM (that I would eventually buy one day, when they become cheaper)?

Comment: @helleye Yup, it supports up to DDR4 3866+(OC) memory modules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should be plenty of Z170 motherboards that support DDR4 3200 MHz memory, otherwise, memory at those speeds wouldn't be sold.

Take a look at this [one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128835&cm_re=z170_mobo-_-13-128-835-_-Product) for example.

As long as the specifications of the motherboard say it supports that speed, you should be fine.